# How to access a local variable with in a foreach loop outside of its scope?

Tags: perl, loops

I have two arrays of string data type and i am comparing those using foreach loops and raising the counter when a match is found

```
my  @array1 = ('India');
my  @array2 = ('India', 'America');
foreach my $a (@array1) {
    foreach my $b (@array2) {
        my $count=0;  
        if($a eq $b) {
             $count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to use this count variable outside of its scope

```
 if ($count > 0) { 
      call_some_function();
 }
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Always put `use strict; use warnings qw(all);` at the beginning of your scripts. Also, please copy-past your real code (that one doesn't even compile).

Answer (score 3):

`$count` is declared into the `foreach` loop, it doesn't exist outside this loop, if you want to use `$count` outside the loop, simply put `my $count=0` before the first `foreach` and remove the one into the `foreach`

here's what you want:

```
my @array1=('India');
my @array2=('India','America');
my $count=0;
foreach my $country1(@array1)
{
   foreach my $country2(@array2)
   {
        if($country1 eq $country2)
        {
             $count++;
        }

   } 
}
```

Comment: I have tried that!....but the count is still showing as zero even though I have matching values in arrays

Comment: do you declare `$a` and `$b` before using them in the loop?, if not, my `my`before  `foreach my $a(@array1)` for example

Comment: @SIVA also why do you put capital letters in `my` `foreach` `if` ?  and why the space between `$` and `count` ?  do you `use strict` `use warnings`? you should always do this

Comment: Using Mobile stack site,it automatically makes the first letter capital after space

Comment: Yes, I do use strict and warnings

Comment: @SIVA, edited my post, but please next time post verifiable code :/

Comment: What would happen when I add next after count++,would it come out of the loop as soon as it matches one value?

Comment: `next;` will jump to the next element of the second loop, `last;` will end your second loop and so, jump to the next element of the first loop. if you want to end your compare on the first match, put `last if $count;` right after the second loop and also right after `$count++`

Comment: `$a` and `$b` are magic variables used by sort. They're a bad idea to use as loop iterators. Above and beyond how single letter variable names are generally bad.

Answer (score 0):

Declare variable outside of the loops, you've also got a typo in $count:

```
my $count = 0;
foreach $a (@array1) {
   foreach $b (@array2) {
      if ( $a eq $b ) {
         $count++;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Tried this,still count has 0 even though there are matching values